# How many GAIA Data Release 2 files are there?

Tags: gaia

I am using this index page to download GDR2 data files.

http://cdn.gea.esac.esa.int/Gaia/gdr2/gaia_source/csv/

But it keeps giving a different number of links. Sometimes it shows 16,000 files, sometimes 31,000 and the max I have seen is 61,237. What is the correct number I should download? GAIA GDR2 documentation does not list the total number of files available.

Interestingly, if the index lists less than 60k files, it still has the closing /html tag so it would appear I have a complete index file, but the contents are not complete.

Comment: Using `curl`, I got 61240 lines total, but that includes some headers, so I think 61237 is correct and your browser may just be timing out. In particular, the last file on my list is "GaiaSource_999922404314639104_1000172126596665472.csv.gz", which seems correct, since the first number increases with each file and seems to finally "wrap around" with the last file.

Comment: Thanks, I did more tests and 61237 seems to be the correct number. Add this as an answer and i will accept it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not really into the points thing, but feel free to post it as your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

barrycarter provided the answer:

Using curl, I got 61240 lines total, but that includes some headers, so I think 61237 is correct and your browser may just be timing out. In particular, the last file on my list is "GaiaSource_999922404314639104_1000172126596665472.csv.gz", which seems correct, since the first number increases with each file and seems to finally "wrap around" with the last file. – barrycarter Apr 29 at 3:54

Answer (score 4):

There are 61,234 data files in the directory. There are three additional (non-data) files:

```
MD5SUM.txt     
_citation.txt  
_disclaimer.txt
```

If you include those, the total number is 61,237.

Comment: Proofs: `curl -s 'http://cdn.gea.esac.esa.int/Gaia/gdr2/gaia_source/csv/MD5SUM.txt' | grep 'GaiaSource_' | wc -l` for the terminal or `[...document.querySelectorAll("a")].filter((el) => /GaiaSource/.test(el.href)).length` for the browser console (F12) in a modern browser.